# Updating rows based on a multiple column condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to update some rows in a table based on two other columns in another table.  As a toy model, consider two tables: People, with columns first_name, last_name, and has_license; Drivers, with columns first_name and last_name.  Now I want to update the first table so has_license='Y' for all tuples of first_name and last_name that are also in the Drivers table.

I could do:

```
UPDATE people SET has_license='Y'
WHERE first_name + last_name IN (SELECT first_name + last_name FROM drivers)
```

(In my actual query, first_name and last_name are an externally-set record id and a date, and the subquery is more complex involving a join/EXCEPT clause.)

That's clumsy and has possible errors depending on the values.  Ideally I could just make the tuple in sql like so:

```
UPDATE people SET has_license='Y'
WHERE (first_name, last_name) IN (SELECT first_name, last_name FROM drivers)
```

But that's invalid SQL (according to SQLite).  So is what I want even possible?

(One other problem is that none of the tables have any primary keys, especially not single-column ones.  If that weren't the case, I would use that to simply identify the row.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **SQL**

Just use a `JOIN`!

```
UPDATE people 
SET has_license='Y'
FROM People
INNER JOIN Drivers
    ON Drivers.First_name = people.first_name
    AND Drivers.Last_name = people.last_name
```

In SQL Server I would just use aliases but I'm not familiar with the intricacies of SQLite syntax.  This should be valid AFAIK.

**EDIT**

Below version uses `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE people 
SET has_license='Y'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Drivers
              WHERE Drivers.First_name = people.first_name
              AND Drivers.Last_name = people.last_name)
```

Comment: AFAICT, in standard SQL the UPDATE statement doesn't have a FROM clause.  It's not in sqlite nor Oracle (the production database) nor the sql guides I could find online.  (And it makes sense, because the result of a join is a temporary, and I need to update something permanent.)

Comment: I'll post a version using `EXISTS`, let me know if it works in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I was hoping for a faster version.  That looks like it will query the Drivers table for each row in the people table.  I was hoping to have something more equivalent to Oracle's `MERGE INTO` command, which production needs for performance.

Comment: You don't know how fast it will run until you run it :)  I don't know about SQLite internals, but in SQL Server this would be very quick.

Comment: Well, I know what I'm trying to replace, an Oracle `MERGE INTO` statement, which would involve three queries.  (The goal is to have developers run unit tests against sqlite.)  This involves one query per row in the people table.  It is 10 times slower on our developer Oracle instance.  Still, I'm beginning to doubt there's anything better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can concatenate the fields:

```
...first_name + last_name) IN (SELECT first_name + last_name...
```

Or

```
...first_name  + ' : ' +  last_name) IN (SELECT first_name  + ' : ' +  last_name...
```