# Updating multiple columns of table based on condition

Tags: database

I want to update multiple columns of a table based on certain condition.
Is there any solution to make the update in single query

I am updating each column on different condition which result in higher cost

--Custom0

```
  IF(xoldcustom0     = xnewcustom0) THEN
      UPDATE table_name
      SET custom0=xxoldcustom0copy
      WHERE id        =column_id
   END IF;
```

--Custom1

```
   IF(xoldcustom1     = xnewcustom1) THEN
      UPDATE table_name
      SET custom1=xxoldcustom1copy
      WHERE id        =column_id
   END IF;
```

can we update the above code in single query based on a condition

Comment: Which database product are you using? The UPDATE would indicate you are using some kind of relational database. But SQL does not have an IF statement, so your example seems to be some kind of programming language that uses embedded SQL

Comment: [See this link, I believe it may be useful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452028/updating-rows-based-on-a-multiple-column-condition)

Comment: I'm using oracle 12c

Answer (score 0):

for each attribute you can get rid of the if-statement:

UPDATE table_name
SET custom1=xxoldcustom1copy
WHERE id =column_id and xoldcustom1 = xnewcustom1

But I see no way to avoid having different statement for each of the attributes / conditions.

Comment: i need to update the based on condition  IF(xoldcustom0     = xnewcustom0) THEN

Comment: but the 

WHERE ... AND xoldcustom1 = xnewcustom1 

ensures that you condition "IF xoldcustom1 = xnewcustom1" is true, doesn't it?

Comment: yes it handle but i need all the condition to be executed into single query. I want to make a dynamic query for UPDATE inside a procedure. The above approach handle single condition

Comment: May be I'm wrong but I see SQL-statement as describing one action ("SET") on a set (in the mathematical sense) of records.

You will be able to define the set of records to be updated based on your conditions (using AND, OR etc.). But then your "UPDATE" clause does not act uniformly on the attributes. So you will habe to prepare a set of attribute values to be used in the SET clause, That could be done by preparing a temporary table. But I must check whether the definition of this temp tab can be integrated into you UPDATE statement.
BTW: why is it important to have only one statement?

Answer (score 0):

Does you RDBMS support WITH-clause (Common Table Expressions, see https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/)?

Then you could try:

WITH temptab (id, custom0, custom1, ...)

AS

(SELECT table_name.id, xxoldcustom0copy, table_name.custom1, .... FROM table_name

WHERE table_name.xoldcustom0 = xnewcustom0 and table_name.id = column_id

UNION

SELECT table_name.id, table_name.custim0, xxoldcustom1copy,  .... FROM table_name

WHERE table_name.xoldcustom1 = xnewcustom1 and table_name.id = column_id

UNION

...

)

update  table_name 
SET custom0=temptab.custom0
SET custom1=temptab.custom1
...
WHERE id =temptab.id;

It seems that MariaDB does not support this syntax so I could not test the statement.